# How to return IQueryable from an oData V4 api action

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, odata

Following the tutorial [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) I'm trying to return IQueryable but I get error *The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed*

```
public class ProductsController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        return GetRepository<Product>().GetQueryable();
    }
}
```

GetRepository() is part of a larger generic DI and Unit of work pattern class that basically

```
public Repository(DbContext context)
{
    Context = context;
    DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
}

public virtual IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
{
    IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;

    return query;
}
```

Comment: Show us `GetRepository`.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I doubt that code is giving the exception. There has to be more.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was asking why I was downvoted

Comment: Still you didn't show `GetRepository`.

Comment: It's probably your DI container that's disposing it. Show the relevant configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return an IQueryable from a controller, you don't have control over when that IQueryable is run.  What is happening is that your DbContext is being disposed before the Web API plumbing is getting around to running the IQueryable and returning the results.

What you are doing with GetRepository is referred to as the Service Locator Pattern. However Web API has a mechanism for doing Dependency Injection, which will give you more deterministic control of the lifetime of your resources.

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Using this approach, you constructor inject your services (the return type of GetRepository), and then override Dispose on your controller so you can clean up your constructor injected services.  Web API will call Dispose on your controller once it has finished running and returning the results from your IQueryable, and thus your lifetime issues will be fixed.

There are wrappers on NuGet for many of the common IOC containers to allow them to work automatically with Web API.

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully on the examples, given in the link you provided, you can see that they have the context outside of the response methods and it is not disposed until Dispose method is called on the controller.

```
    public class ProductsController : ODataController
        {
            ProductsContext db = new ProductsContext();

            [EnableQuery]
            public IQueryable<Product> Get()
            {
               return db.Products;
            }         

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }
```

Most likely, you dispose the created context in your GetRepository() or GetQueryable() methods. For example, by applying `using`.

Comment: I was disposing of an IoC container inside the controller method,  disposing the container in the override solved my problem!